# How to change the segmented control actions when click on button?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

Hi in my application i want to change the segmented control actions when click on button.Here i am attaching my image.

[image]

In above image default segmented control is =0 and when i click on + button segmented control changed to 1.

Comment: u bind action method of segmented control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on button click change  segmented control -> selectedSegmentIndex

```
Tempsegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
```

and call action which  bind on value changed

```
- (IBAction)TempsegmentAction:(id)sender 
{
    if (Tempsegment.selectedSegmentIndex==0) 
    {
       // for segment index 0
    }
    else
    {
      // for segment index 1
    }
}
```